# Hector mapping generates empty map

Tags: gazebo, navigation, mapping, ros-hydro, hector-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use following launch file to run hector mapping on turtlebot. It don't gives any error also don't create any map. When I enter `rosrun map_server map_saver -f ~/mymap` mymap.pgm is light gray image.

Original launch file

```
<launch>
  <include file="$(find turtlebot_gazebo)/launch/turtlebot_empty_world.launch" />
  <include file="$(find hector_mapping)/launch/mapping_default.launch">
    <arg name="pub_map_odom_transform" value="true" />
    <arg name="base_frame" value="base_footprint" />
    <arg name="odom_frame" value="odom" />
  </include>
  <include file="$(find hector_geotiff)/launch/geotiff_mapper.launch">
    <arg name="trajectory_publish_rate" value="4" />
  </include>
  <node pkg="hector_pose_estimation" type="pose_estimation" name="hector_pose_estimation" output="screen" />
  <include file="$(find turtlebot_rviz_launchers)/launch/view_robot.launch" />
</launch>
```

Graph of this launch file is like this. I couldn't find the problem.
[image: rqt_graph]
[rqt_graph](https://i.imgur.com/Hp4VDtc.png)

[image: tf view_frames]
[tf view_frames](https://i.imgur.com/iTvkbZT.png)

Latest launch file

```
<launch>
    <include file="$(find turtlebot_gazebo)/launch/turtlebot_empty_world.launch" />
    <include file="$(find turtlebot_rviz_launchers)/launch/view_robot.launch" />
    <include file="$(find hector_mapping)/launch/mapping_default.launch">
        <arg name="pub_map_odom_transform" value="false" />
    </include>
    <include file="$(find hector_geotiff)/launch/geotiff_mapper.launch">
        <arg name="trajectory_publish_rate" value="4" />
    </include>
    <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="odom_to_map" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /map /odom 100"/>
</launch>
```

[Bag file with /scan and /tf topics](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21699640/hector_mapping_turtlebot.bag)

All of the sollutions are merged as a package at [Github](https://github.com/ormanli/turtlebot-hector-mapping)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193157/hector-mapping-generates-empty-map/) by [serdar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20095/serdar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-09-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-09-21**:
cross check laser is published in base_footprint frame.

**Comment by [serdar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20095/serdar/) on 2014-09-22**:
@bvbdort Is it wrong that laserscan_nodelet_manager is publishing scan? In rviz I can see laser scan in /scan topic.

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-09-22**:
check the frame id of laser scan it should be `base_footprint` or any other frame which has tf with `base_footprint`. Can you share your `rosrun tf view_frames` output.

**Comment by [serdar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20095/serdar/) on 2014-09-22**:
@bvbdort I added `rosrun tf view_frames` output to question body.

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-09-22**:
what is the frame id of laser; you can view it from `rostopic echo /scan`

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-09-22**:
Also use

**Comment by [serdar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20095/serdar/) on 2014-09-22**:
@bvbdort frame id of scan is /camera_depth_frame.

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-09-22**:
use `<arg name="pub_map_odom_transform" value="false"/`> , hope it works

**Comment by [serdar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20095/serdar/) on 2014-09-22**:
@bvbdort When I pass false to pub_map_odom_transform, in rviz Transform status section it prints **No transform from [map] to [base_footprint]**.

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-09-22**:
Change frame in rviz to map to view map

**Comment by [serdar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20095/serdar/) on 2014-09-22**:
I always change but it always shows light gray square, never draws map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

use `<arg name="pub_map_odom_transform" value="false"/>`

and add static tf between /map and /odom in your .launch file

```
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="odom_to_map" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /map /odom 100"/>
```

**Edit :**

remove running `hector_pose_estimation` from launch file. Pose not required for hector slam.

```
<node pkg="hector_pose_estimation" type="pose_estimation" name="hector_pose_estimation" output="screen" />
```

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [serdar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20095/serdar/) on 2014-09-23**:
Now map rotates with movement but map is empty again.

**Comment by [serdar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20095/serdar/) on 2014-09-23**:
I added latest launch file to question. It is not working.

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-09-23**:
can you share your bag file with /tf and /scan topics

**Comment by [serdar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20095/serdar/) on 2014-09-23**:
I added bag file to question.

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-09-24**:
@serdar i am able to see the map [screen shot here](https://imgur.com/rtosX1l)  but it was not proper. I used default launch file  `tutorial.launch` in `hector_slam_launch` . try moving view_robot.launch before maping.launch

**Comment by [serdar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20095/serdar/) on 2014-09-25**:
I don't know what problem is. First I run `rosbag play hector_mapping_turtlebot.bag` then `roslaunch hector_slam_launch tutorial.launch`. When rviz opens I add map from by topic section. There is no error but, there is no map.

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-09-25**:
first run `roslaunch hector_slam_launch tutorial.launch` and then `rosbag play hector_mapping_turtlebot.bag --clock`

**Comment by [serdar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20095/serdar/) on 2014-09-25**:
@bvbdort Thanks. I see some inaccurate map. Did you have any idea what is problem and why I cannot generate map from my launch file?

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-09-25**:
Issue might be with low laser frequency fr your bag its around 10hz, but hector slam need around 40 hz. Did you try with first mapping.launch  and later robot.launch ?

**Comment by [serdar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20095/serdar/) on 2014-09-25**:
It didn't make any difference.

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-09-25**:
try removing args from launch file

```
<arg name="base_frame" value="base_footprint" />
        <arg name="odom_frame" value="odom" />
```

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-09-25**:
i didnt see any problem in launch file. Can you update current frames.pdf and rqt_graph in question.

**Comment by [serdar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20095/serdar/) on 2014-09-25**:
I updated rqt_graph and framed.pdf.

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2014-09-26**:
Note that running hector_mapping with simulated laserscans from Kinect is probably not going to work very well (see also http://answers.ros.org/question/33933/kinect-doing-hector-slam/)

**Comment by [serdar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20095/serdar/) on 2014-09-26**:
@Stefan Kohlbrecher Thanks. I can try it with another robot. Do you have any suggestion for robot on gazebo ?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2014-09-26**:
Well, if you´re only in Gazebo, you can easily install a (simulated) LIDAR on your robot :)

**Comment by [serdar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20095/serdar/) on 2014-09-26**:
Your turtlebot on github worked. Thanks.

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-09-27**:
did your map worked finally ?

**Comment by [serdar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20095/serdar/) on 2014-09-28**:
@bvbdort Turtlebot [at this link](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_turtlebot) worked. With laser it worked. But it moves autonomously. I am trying to figure out what is causing it. Teleop isn't working. After that I will post proper launch file. Thanks for your support.